# Customizing view on Month view with FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I changed the `className` tag on the daily and weekly view of [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to show the status of items in the calendar.

The problem is in month view all events are styled the same. Is there a way to override this with a custom CSS tag? I tried `color`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: what is full calendar is that a plugin? maybe u dont mind showing us some code?

Comment: Try adding !important such as color: #ffffff !important;

Comment: FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin.. a rather nice one at that.. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use a separate `className` for the events you wish to appear separate.  EG:

```
events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
        className: 'Myevent_1'
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d-2),
        className: 'Myevent_2'
    },
    ... ...
```

Then structure the styles, like so (at a minimum):

```
.Myevent_1, .Myevent_1 .fc-event-skin {
    background: gold;
}
.Myevent_2, .Myevent_2 .fc-event-skin {
    background: red;
}
```

[**See a demo at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNu3r/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brock..

The issue was i used:

```
.subOpen,
.fc-agenda .subOpen .fc-event-time,
.subOpen a {
    background-color:#FFFF33;
    color: #000000;
}
```

I actually upgraded from FullCalendar 1.3 to 1.5.1 which now can be passed the following as part of the Even Object.

**color** , **backgroundColor** , **BorderColor** , and **textColor**. [Ref: FullCalendar Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

When used they override the CSS in fullCalendar.css as well as pass the settings to all views correctly.

So instead of using CSS I am passing the color settings with the event data like so.

```
 [{"title":"Thomas Trutt","start":"2011-05-30 09:00","end":"2011-05-30 22:00","id":"28","opID":"3","allDay":false,"color":"#36F"}]
```

This works out since all of my events are being pulled from a database.

Thanks again